# How to have a click event on an appended class using $(this);

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to get the text on a click event of appended HTML.

All I can find is `$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function ()`. 
This works only for one and not in the each function

Have tried an `each(function ()`

```
$(document).on('click', '.myClass', function () {
    var x = $(this).text();
    alert(x);
});
```

Expecting to get text on click of appended HTML

Comment: Did you try `$('.myClass').click(function() { });`?

Comment: By appended HTML do you mean the HTML is added using JS?

Comment: @sanketd617 the wording of the question implies the HTML has been added after doc.ready, so OP should be using event delegation, which hey are.  So not clear why it's not working, but unlikely to be fixed by using direct events.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code as presented.  Can you create a snippet that demonstrates the problem?   (edit question, snippet button).    Are there any console errors (eg jquery not included correctly or included after your script)?

Comment: Your code working: https://jsfiddle.net/afcnbhLp/

Comment: For example $("th").append("<p class='myClass''>My text</p>"); And then each loop on myClass that gets text

Comment: No need for an `each` function.

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I meant. I mean getting text that has been appended by JS

Comment: $('td').each(function () {
        $(this).bind('mouseenter', function () {
            if (this.offsetWidth < this.scrollWidth && !$(this).attr('title')) {
                $(this).attr('title', $(this).text());
                $(this).append("<p class='myClass'>" + $(this).attr('title') + "</p>");
            }
        });
    });                  And then go through each that has an ellipsis getting text on click. The problem is I need to loop through and get text on $(this)

Comment: You might like to update your question with your *actual* problem then, because "get text on $(this)" is trivial and clearly not the only issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ftpgcwz5/ works. The issue is likely related to something else. Other elements covering so the click does not register? Event propagation being stopped somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get the text in the tag after append them?

Try this

```
$("#test1").on('click', function () {
  $(this).append("<p class='myClassB'>abc</p> <p class='myClassB'>xyz</p>");
  var a = [];
  $(".myClassB").each(function(x) {
    a.push($(this).text());
  });
  alert(a);
});
```